# forEach loop in google scripts

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, foreach, spreadsheet

I had a function that did what I wanted for one row at a time. Now I want to apply that to multiple rows so I'm trying to use a forEach loop. I'm not throwing errors, but I'm also not getting what I want! (Nothing is output to the cell, and Logger.log only shows Range)

I'm trying to compare a list (from a row) of jobs employees worked the week against the main list of jobs available and then return just the list of worked jobs back to the spreadsheet in a specific cell.

The row in the spreadsheet has more than just the jobs in it, which is why I pull every third item. Some cells have more than one job code in them as well.

The initial one row function:

```
/**
 * Test Returns the job codes assigned for the week
 * must be entered like this: =TWOJOBS(CELL("address",B12)&":"&CELL("address",AC12))
 * @param {Range} Employee's Info Range 
 * @return {List} How many days of work per job code
 * @customfunction
 */


function TWOJOBS(pRange) {
  //get the current active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FULL YEAR 2021");
//get the Named Range of JOBS
  var JobList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("JOBS");
//get the Job Codes
  var jobjob = JobList.getValues();
  var jobjobjob = String(jobjob)
//get the length of the Job List
  var joblength = jobjobjob.length;
//Logger.log(joblength); 
//get the values from the input range
  var empData = ss.getRange(pRange);
  var empWeek = empData.getValues()[0];
  var empDatalst = [];
  
  for(var k=0; k<empWeek.length; k++){
    empDatalst.push(String(empWeek[k]).split());
  }
  /*get every third item in the EmpDatalst array*/
  const every_nth = (arr, nth) => arr.filter((e, i) => i % nth === nth - 1);
  var empJobs = every_nth(empDatalst, 3);

  var indivEmplJobs = [];
  var innyEmJojo = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<empJobs.length; i++){
   //for(var j=0; j<empJobs[i].length; j++){
     indivEmplJobs.push(String(empJobs[i]).split(";"));
    } 
  for (var i = 0;i<indivEmplJobs.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<indivEmplJobs[i].length; j++){
      innyEmJojo.push((indivEmplJobs[i][j]).trim())
   }
  }  
  var jobsworked = [];
  for(var i=0; i<joblength; i++){
       if(innyEmJojo.includes(String((jobjob[i])))){
      jobsworked.push(String((jobjob[i])));    
      }
  }
```

And then the multi-row function (I have named ranges for each week):

```
    /**
 * Test Returns the job codes assigned for the week
 * Assign this script to a button to get the info for the week
 * @param {Range} Employee's Info Range 
 * @return {List} How many days of work per job code
 * @customfunction
 */


function TestWeek29Jobs() {
  //get the current active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //get the Named Range of JOBS
  var JobList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("JOBS");
  //get the Job Codes
  var jobjob = JobList.getValues();
  var jobjobjob = String(jobjob)
  //get the length of the Job List
  var joblength = jobjobjob.length;

  //get the named range of the week
  var empData = ss.getRangeByName("Week29");
  //var empData = ss.getRange("B787:V787");
  //get the values in the range
  var empWeek = empData.getValues();
  
  var empDatalst = [];

  empWeek.forEach(function(person){
      //Logger.log(empData.getRow());
      for(var k=0; k<empWeek.length; k++){
      empDatalst.push(String(empWeek[k]).split());
          }//end k for
        /*get every third item in the EmpDatalst array because every third is just the job code*/
      const every_nth = (arr, nth) => arr.filter((e, i) => i % nth === nth - 1);
      var empJobs = every_nth(empDatalst, 3);

      var indivEmplJobs = [];
      var innyEmJojo = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<empJobs.length; i++){
        indivEmplJobs.push(String(empJobs[i]).split(";"));
        }//end i for loop
      for (var i = 0;i<indivEmplJobs.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<indivEmplJobs[i].length; j++){
          innyEmJojo.push((indivEmplJobs[i][j]).trim())
            }//end j for loop
          }//end i for loop  
      var jobsworked = [];
      for(var i=0; i<joblength; i++){
        if(innyEmJojo.includes(String((jobjob[i])))){
          jobsworked.push(String((jobjob[i]))); 
        }//end if
      }//end for 

      var text = ""
      var row = empData.getRow();
      var targetcell = ss.getRange("AA"+row);
      for (var j=0; j<jobsworked.length; j++){
      if(jobsworked[j] != ""){
        text += jobsworked[j]+",";        
            }//end if
         targetcell.setValue(text);
         Logger.log(targetcell);
          }//end for
  }); //end of forEach
}//end of function
```

Can anyone help guide me if I'm WAY off or if I'm just missing something in the forEach functionality? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Array.forEach(function(item) {})` will execute a function for each element of `Array`, which is represented by `item`.

In your implementation:

```
empWeek.forEach(function(person){
  // code here
});
```

Since `empWeek` is now a 2D array, each element is now a 1D array, so `person` is now equal to `empWeek[0]`, `empWeek[1]`, so on, each is a 1D array.

So to access a single cell value, you need to put an index to `person`:

```
for(var k=0; k<person.length; k++){
  empDatalst.push(String(person[k]).split());
}
```

Also in the last code block, since you will be now writing to multiple rows, you need to increment `row` for each execution, so you need to put an index on the `forEach` function parameter. `idx` starts from 0 and increments by 1 for each function execution.

```
empWeek.forEach(function(person, idx){
  var empDatalst = [];
  for(var k=0; k<person.length; k++){
    empDatalst.push(String(person[k]).split());
  }

  // code here

  var text = "";
  var row = empData.getRow()+idx;
  var targetcell = ss.getRange("AA"+row);
  for (var j=0; j<jobsworked.length; j++) {
    if (jobsworked[j] != "") {
      text += jobsworked[j]+",";        
            }//end if
      targetcell.setValue(text);
      Logger.log(text);
    }
});
```

**Reference:**

[forEach() JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I suspected the person index bit, but without the incrementing rows I couldn't see any of the results! This worked like magic!

Comment: Thanks for the response, the community would appreciate if you would accept the answer if it helps solve your problem. [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)